# Django create or update from list to model

Tags: django

I have this model:

```
class ring(models.Model):
    size= models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Ring Size', default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
```

the existing data are:

```
[2.2, 2.5, 3.0, 3.2, 4.2, 4.5, 4.8, 5.5, 5.8, 6.0]
```

user edited the initial data from template and generate these:

```
[2.1, 2.5, 3.0, 3.2, 4.2, 4.5, 4.8, 5.5, 5.7, 6.1, 6.5, 7.5, 8.0, 9.0, 11.0, 13.0, 15.0, 16.0]
```

**I want to do this:**

1. If those numbers are not existed, create a new one.
2. If user update the number lets say from 2.2 to 2.1 , 5.8 to 5.7 then
   just update the existing.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the user will be returning a complete list as input. In such a case, you will have to retrieve all values and check if some of them are updated or remain the same, or are added new. This can be messy and suboptimal, in my view.

The simplest method to avoid this will be to delete all values from the table and insert these new values. As there is no other field, and in the database, the order doesn't matter, it will get the same results as what you want.

In your views.py add this to your view (valList is the input from user):

```
ring.objects.all().delete()

for i in range(len(valList)):
    r = ring(size = valList[i])
    if r is not None:
        r.save()
```